# Calling method with error: Expected argument (Variable) ->()

Tags: swift, function, methods, completionhandler

I am trying to call a method with a completion handler, but I can't seem to call it without this error. I am confused on what its asking for.

Here is the method I can calling:

```
 func fillFromFile(completionBlock: @escaping ([Asset_Content]) -> ()) {
    let url = "URLSTRING"

    LoadJSONFile(from: url) { (result) in
        // The code inside this block would be called when LoadJSONFile is completed. this could happen very quickly, or could take a long time

        //.map is an easier way to transform/iterate over an array
        var newContentArray = [Asset_Content]()
        for json in result{
            let category = json["BIGCATEGORY"] as? String
            let diagnosis = json["DIAGNOSIS"] as? String
            let perspective = json["PERSPECTIVE"] as? String
            let name = json["NAME"] as? String
            let title = json["Title"] as? String
            let UnparsedTags = json["TAGS"] as? String
            let filename = json["FILENAME"] as? String

            let tagArray = UnparsedTags?.characters.split(separator: ",")
            for tag in tagArray!{
                if(!self.ListOfTags.contains(String(tag))){
                    self.ListOfTags.append(String(tag))
                }
            }

            let asset = Asset_Content(category!, diagnosis!, perspective!, name!, title!, filename!)
            // This is a return to the map closure. We are still in the LoadJSONFile completion block
            newContentArray.append(asset)

        }
        print("return count ", newContentArray.count)
        // This is the point at which the passed completion block is called. 
        completionBlock(newContentArray)
    }
}
```

Comment: what error do you get ?

Comment: When I try to call it with just the method call, I get "Missing argument for 'CompletionBlock' in call"

Comment: check  the parameters you are passing to get that URL Function in work. maybe it need some integer value and you are passings string which cause missing arguments